# SalesForce with iOS Customer Portal

Tags: ios, salesforce

I am using zkSForce with iOS for direct access to our SalesForce data and for logging in and viewing cases for customer portal users.  This all works, a customer portal user can log in to the app and see the cases and make queries, etc.

The problem I have is, before the user is a customer portal user, they are a Person Account.  We are able to go into SalesForce and select to enable the Person Account as a customer portal user.  But what we want to do is be able to do this from the iOS device.  From the device, we want to be able to say:  Enable customer portal license for AccountId xxxxxx.

Have no idea how we would or if we can actually do this...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "it's better to not do it". Sorry, I feel the answer to this would be more philosophical than truly programming-related.

Obviously Customer Portal/Guest user cannot enable himself as a damn actual user. It would be wrong on so many levels:

1. He/she would be able to select to which Account he wants to be associated, out of many interesting possibilities ;)
2. If he can "elevate" himself that would defeat the whole purpose of limiting Cust. Portal user's options in the first place.
3. Hackers, data miners & screen scraping applications welcome!
4. You guys **pay** for Cust. Portal licenses.

So... you can hardcode username & pass of a dedicated "SysAdmin" user in your iOS app that'd connect and fix the data. Except what if it's hacked or password expires?

Or you can build something like "request Access" screen? Whatever. A form which they'd fill in (I'm John Smith, I work for company XYZ, my Email is ..., I need access because of Case 0123456, somebody I know at your org is...) and then either a human being looks at it or you leverage Web-To-Lead, Email-To-Case, a Site page or whatever to programmatically decide what to do with it?

Comment: While I appreciate your concern and you have valid points, the app will not allow them to do much so security is not a concern.  What do you mean what if it is hacked?  If someone was able to guess the password?  You can't decompile an iOS app so I dont see how it could be hacked.  Anyway, I figured it out, it is not too difficult.  With ZKSObject, you simply create a contact from the Account then with that contactId, you can create the user.